# Clear screen when ENTER is typed during script run (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a simple script which displays a simple CLI output when run, which is periodically refreshed. However, when ENTER is pressed, the final row of output stays after the script has refreshed, which is untidy.

I'm looking to trap the ENTER keystroke so that, whenever at any point in the script ENTER is pressed, the `clear` command will be run (allowing the script to redraw the output neatly).

Is there a way to do this in bash? I could not find any online.

Thanks!

EDIT: to clarify, I'm hoping for something like the following - say I have a script which prints out a `.` once a second:

```
while true; do
    sleep 1
    echo -n '.'
done
```

What I'm hoping to add is code that, if ENTER is pressed at any point, will clear all dots from the screen.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable question, but could you please include code for a minimal toy example?

Comment: Absolutely right - I've added a small example to try and clarify what I'm looking for. Thanks!